# How to declare singly linked-list in c?

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

Can anyone explain what the difference between the following declarations of a single linked list in c is? More specifically, why the first one isn't correct?

```
typedef struct
{
    char *data;
    struct linkedlist *next;
} linkedlist;
```

vs

```
typedef struct linkedlist
{
    char *data;
    struct linkedlist *next;
} linkedlist;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case, the compiler reaches

```
struct linkedlist *next;
```

and it doesn't know what a `struct linkedlist` is.

In the second case, you tell it at the start of the struct declaration that it's a `struct linkedlist`. This makes the compiler happy when it later encounters the `next` field.

Comment: why does the compiler (gcc in my case) does not complain at struct definition, but give me some errors later?

Comment: One error is for an instruction "while (tmp->next->next)" gives me "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type", where tmp is a "linkedlist *"

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct
{
  ...
} linkedlist;
```

The above allow you to be able to declare variables as follows:

```
linkedlist thisIsALinkedList;
```

But the problem is this is only parsed by the compiler at the end of the struct. So when it reaches  `struct linkedlist *next` it doesn't know what `linkedlist` is (and even if it did, the declaration still would've been incorrect, since it should've been just `linkedlist *next`).